# How to make a sudoku board with a predetermined solution

Tags: python, tkinter, sudoku

So, i have made a very basic sudoku board using tkinter where you can click on a box on the 9x9 grid and enter any number 1-9 however i wasn't sure how to create a random board with the solution already known, i was thinking of making a board and then taking out some numbers so it is partly blank, but i don't know how to make the given numbers unchangable or how to make a program that can create random completed sudoku boards.

This is how to board is currently created:

```
number_list = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
]
```

my question is:
How do I create completed board, and takes out parts of the board to make it a puzzle?

Comment: This sounds like a whole project. You can split that into parts like: the gui part, and the actual sudoku part. Please ask specific questions.

Comment: You should focus on only one problem per question

Answer (score 1):

Sudoku puzzle needs to have a single solution. The solution is a filled board 9x9. The puzzle part is to fill the board given its subset. So for the game you would need two pieces of data: the solved board and the starting combination that can only lead to this solution.

## The gameplay

Given a solved board and a starting board you do not need any additional logic – just check if user’s next move matched the solved board.

There are different ways to score the solution. The user can be notified every time he makes an incorrect move, or he could not be able to make such move at all. The more restrictions you introduce the easier it would be to solve the puzzle. This is not always what the user wants so be careful with it.

You can also give hints when solving. For example highlight all numbers that are the same as selected, or give the user a way to rule out certain numbers for a given cell.

## Generating the puzzle

You start with any solved board (a quick tip you can move row or column as long as it stays in same 3x3 block to get a different board).
Then you need to start removing elements. The important bit here is you need to make sure that the board can be solved and has only one solution. As always synthesis is the next step after analysis. So for it you would need to write a sudoku solver.
This process might be computationally heavy so it should at least cache the result instead of generating on the fly.

### Complexity

Complexity in sudoku puzzle comes from 3 properties of the puzzle

1. The number of next available moves
2. The number of moves needed to check assumptions
3. The number of concurrent assumptions

The number of next available moves is very high (>2) for a simple level puzzle. And gets lower as complexity increases. So for your solver you should add this setting.
The hard level puzzles might have a situation with 0 next available moves which brings us to the assumptions. Having no available moves does not mean the puzzle is unsolvable, there could be cells with few available options left and the task is to rule out incorrect ones. For that one would make an assumption and will try to disprove it. And the number of moves required increases complexity of the puzzle.
And finally there can be multiple assumptions required, this is for the extreme complexity level puzzles.

### Implementation

I will not write the `*_board` functions but given you have them the implementation should look something like this:

```
solved_board = get_solved_board()
solved_board = shuffle_board(solved_board)
complexity_rules = dict(min_moves_available=3, max_assumptions=0, max_assumption_moves=0)
starting_board = copy.deepcopy(solved_board)
while True:
    next_starting_board = copy.deepcopy(starting_board)
    next_starting_board = remove_random_elements(next_starting_board)
    if solve_board(complexity_rules, next_starting_board):
        starting_board = next_starting_board
    else:
        break
return solved_board, starting_board
```

You might want to have a better loop than this, but is a good starting point.

---

Please check other posts on this topic https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/56149/81296